# Can't install tidyverse on latest version of Linux Mint

Tags: r, tidyverse, linux-mint

So here is a snippet of the error message:

```
**cpp11.cpp:24:409: error: ‘unmove’ is not a member of ‘cpp11’
   24 |     return cpp11::as_sexp(melt_dataframe(cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::data_frame>(data)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<const cpp11::integers&>(id_ind)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<const cpp11::integers&>(measure_ind)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::strings>(variable_name)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::strings>(value_name)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::sexp>(attrTemplate)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<bool>(factorsAsStrings)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<bool>(valueAsFactor)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<bool>(variableAsFactor))));
      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^~~~~~
cpp11.cpp:24:463: error: ‘unmove’ is not a member of ‘cpp11’
   24 |     return cpp11::as_sexp(melt_dataframe(cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::data_frame>(data)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<const cpp11::integers&>(id_ind)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<const cpp11::integers&>(measure_ind)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::strings>(variable_name)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::strings>(value_name)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::sexp>(attrTemplate)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<bool>(factorsAsStrings)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<bool>(valueAsFactor)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<bool>(variableAsFactor))));
      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^~~~~~
cpp11.cpp:24:514: error: ‘unmove’ is not a member of ‘cpp11’
   24 |     return cpp11::as_sexp(melt_dataframe(cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::data_frame>(data)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<const cpp11::integers&>(id_ind)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<const cpp11::integers&>(measure_ind)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::strings>(variable_name)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::strings>(value_name)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::sexp>(attrTemplate)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<bool>(factorsAsStrings)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<bool>(valueAsFactor)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<bool>(variableAsFactor))));
      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ^~~~~~
cpp11.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* _tidyr_simplifyPieces(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)’:
cpp11.cpp:31:49: error: ‘unmove’ is not a member of ‘cpp11’
   31 |     return cpp11::as_sexp(simplifyPieces(cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::list>(pieces)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<int>(p)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<bool>(fillLeft))));
      |                                                 ^~~~~~
cpp11.cpp:31:100: error: ‘unmove’ is not a member of ‘cpp11’
   31 |     return cpp11::as_sexp(simplifyPieces(cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::list>(pieces)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<int>(p)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<bool>(fillLeft))));
      |                                                                                                    ^~~~~~
cpp11.cpp:31:138: error: ‘unmove’ is not a member of ‘cpp11’
   31 |     return cpp11::as_sexp(simplifyPieces(cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<cpp11::list>(pieces)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<int>(p)), cpp11::unmove(cpp11::as_cpp<bool>(fillLeft))));
      |                                   **
```

It seems like CPP issue.

I have already ran:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev xml2 libxml2-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev unixodbc-dev
```

> sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 20

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] nloptr_1.2.2.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3
```

I have no clue. This doesn't make any sense. Please help. There is enough details.

Comment: Looks like this issue has been reported: https://github.com/r-lib/cpp11/issues/88

Comment: So does that mean there isn't a solution currently? We have to wait?

Comment: @unathletic_coder we have to wait for cran to be updated. Alternatively install cpp11 0.1.0 first using ```remotes::install_version("cpp11", "0.1.0")``` and then install tidyverse without updating any packages when asked

Comment: @RyanJField Is there a expected time for when cran will be updated?

Comment: That other question has some workaround suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63348135/error-installing-tidyr-on-ubuntu-18-04-r-4-0-2

Comment: @unathletic_coder the package has just been updated on CRAN to [0.2.1](https://cran.r-project.org/package=cpp11), not sure how long it will take to propagate / become available, shouldn't be too long hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution (R comunity) after lots of tries. Before install Tidyverse in R, at the command line in Mint you needed to install several packages:

`sudo apt-get install r-base-dev xml2 libxml2-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev unixodbc-dev`

and it works for me.